# To claim credit against luck

Tags: american-english, british-english

I'd need to translate into English an expression which describes somebody quite unlucky. Is the expression in the title (literal translation from my language) what would you say in English or please could you suggest any elegant expressions for it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Be down on one’s luck](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/down+on+luck)***  is an idiomatic expression that conveys the idea you are referring to:

> - Afflicted by misfortune, as in *They've been down on their luck ever since they moved out West*. [Colloquial; second half of 1800s]

(AHD)